# Can't open plot window for OpenStreetMap on Mac OS : unable to create quartz() device target

Tags: r, openstreetmap

I am using the latest OpenStreetMap library on Mac OS. I am able to download a map, but I execute the plot(map) command, I get an error saying "unable to create quartz() device target, given type may not be supported". Can anyone help?

```
> library(OpenStreetMap)
Loading required package: rJava
Loading required package: raster
Loading required package: sp
Loading required package: rgdal
rgdal: version: 0.8-16, (SVN revision 498)
Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 1.10.1, released 2013/08/26
Path to GDAL shared files: /opt/local/share/gdal
Loaded PROJ.4 runtime: Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012, [PJ_VERSION: 480]
Path to PROJ.4 shared files: (autodetected)
> upperLeft  <- c(lat= 37.950, lon= -122.553)
> lowerRight <- c(lat= 37.650, lon= -122.250)
> mapMercator = openmap(upperLeft, lowerRight, minNumTiles=9,type="esri")
> map <- openproj(mapMercator)
> plot(map)
Error in (function (title, width, height, pointsize, family, antialias,  : 
  unable to create quartz() device target, given type may not be supported
```

Interestingly, if I add a single **plot(0,0)** before the calling openmap(), the map will be displayed but with a warning "Process manager already initialized -- can't fully enable headless mode."

```
> library(OpenStreetMap)
Loading required package: rJava
Loading required package: raster
Loading required package: sp
Loading required package: rgdal
rgdal: version: 0.8-16, (SVN revision 498)
Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 1.10.1, released 2013/08/26
Path to GDAL shared files: /opt/local/share/gdal
Loaded PROJ.4 runtime: Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012, [PJ_VERSION: 480]
Path to PROJ.4 shared files: (autodetected)
> plot(0,0)
> upperLeft  <- c(lat= 37.950, lon= -122.553)
> lowerRight <- c(lat= 37.650, lon= -122.250)
> mapMercator = openmap(upperLeft, lowerRight, minNumTiles=9,type="esri")
2014-02-20 12:45:46.592 R[2539:607] Process manager already initialized -- can't fully enable headless mode.
> map <- openproj(mapMercator)
> plot(map)
```